# How to simplify this code and remove the if-else block?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can anybody help me in code simplification so that i don't have to write a if-else block and can get all the private posts if the user is a admin user
or return the private posts by the current user?

```
@main.route('/private')
@login_required
def private():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    if current_user.username == "admin":
        posts = Post.query\
                    .filter_by(is_private=True)\
                    .order_by(Post.date_posted.desc())\
                    .paginate(per_page=5, page=page)
    else:
        posts = Post.query\
                    .filter_by(is_private=True, author=current_user)\
                    .order_by(Post.date_posted.desc())\
                    .paginate(per_page=5, page=page)
    return render_template('private.html', title="Private", posts=posts)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@main.route('/private')
@login_required
def private():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    kwargs = {'author' : current_user} \
        if current_user.username != "admin" else {}

    posts = Post.query\
                .filter_by(is_private=True, **kwargs)\
                .order_by(Post.date_posted.desc())\
                .paginate(per_page=5, page=page)
    return render_template('private.html', title="Private", posts=posts)
```

This should add the `author=current_user` kwarg to your method call only if the user isn't admin. Otherwise, `**kwargs` will just unpack an empty dictionary and won't add anything.

Comment: If i am correct you are using a dictionary to store key value pairs and dereferencing it??

Comment: when using '\*\*' on a dict, it basically unpacks all the key/value pairs. This lets you pass a variable amount of arguments to a function. You can do the same with positional arguments, although that just uses a single '*'. Take a look at [this](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/), it should go a little more into it.

Comment: No problem! I just made a quick edit to trim down the lines of code a bit more, using a ternary operation to assign kwargs instead of assigning a default and then adding the key inside an 'if' statement.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique that simply refactors the common parts into code that *follows* the `if` statement.

```
@main.route('/private')
@login_required
def private():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)

    if current_user.username == "admin":
        query = Post.query.filter_by(is_private=True)           
    else:
        query = Post.query.filter_by(is_private=True, author=current_user)

    posts = query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(per_page=5, page=page)
    return render_template('private.html', title="Private", posts=posts)
```